# margin-top moving along with the #section div?

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to move the class `.column` below `50px`, but `margin-top: 50px` moving along with the `#section`. Why is that and how it can be fixed?

```css
*{ padding:0; margin:0; }

body { width:100%; font-family:"Source Sans Pro" }
#section { height:400px; background-color:#383838; color:White; }
span { font-size:40px; }
.column { width: 300px; border: 2px solid yellow; margin-left:40px; margin-top:50px; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Breadth</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="breadth.css" />
    <link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="section">
            <div class="column">
                <span class="icon icon-cogs"></span>
                <h2>Maecenas lectus sapien</h2>
                <p>In posuere eleifend odio. Quisque semper augue mattis wisi. Pellentesque viverra vulputate enim. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `padding-top: 50px` to `#section` rather than `margin-top` to `.column`

**Referring from Mozilla Documentation:**

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Read about [Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) for more details.

```css
*{ padding:0; margin:0; }

body{ width:100%; font-family:"Source Sans Pro" }
#section{height:400px; background-color:#383838; color:White; padding-top: 50px; }
span{  font-size:40px; }
.column{ width: 300px; border: 2px solid yellow; margin-left:40px;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Breadth</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="breadth.css" />
    <link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="section">
            <div class="column">
                <span class="icon icon-cogs"></span>
                <h2>Maecenas lectus sapien</h2>
                <p>In posuere eleifend odio. Quisque semper augue mattis wisi. Pellentesque viverra vulputate enim. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to know why margin-top is not working...@Muhammad

Comment: I've shared a link plz read it, its bcz of collapsing margins

Comment: @Sabari if you really wants to stick with `margin-top` then apply `overflow: hidden` to `#section` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `margin-top` then give `display:block` to parent div and `display:inline-block` to child div.

See [here](http://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/eZaWvY)

Fore more info read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

**Edited CSS**

*{ padding:0; margin:0; }

```
body{ width:100%; font-family:"Source Sans Pro" }
#section{height:400px; background-color:#383838; color:White;display:block; }
span{  font-size:40px; }
.column{ width: 300px; border: 2px solid yellow; margin-left:40px;  margin-top:50px;display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `padding-top` for `#section` like in the fiddle and remove `margin-top` from child. Since `margin`s will collapse to each other, it's better not to use it for positioning elements. refer this:  [Margin goes outside div when border is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979945/margin-goes-outside-div-when-border-is-removed/15980020#15980020)

```
#section {
   padding-top: 40px;
   ...
}
```

Another approach is use the same code but add `overflow:auto` to #section like this:

```
#section {
   overflow:auto;
   ...
}
```

There's another solutions too like using border on parent, but these are more like hacks since we used margins for positioning.

```css
*{ padding:0; margin:0; }

body { width:100%; font-family:"Source Sans Pro" }
#section { height:400px; background-color:#383838; color:White; padding-top:50px;}
span { font-size:40px; }
.column { width: 300px; border: 2px solid yellow; margin-left:40px;  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Breadth</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="breadth.css" />
    <link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="section">
            <div class="column">
                <span class="icon icon-cogs"></span>
                <h2>Maecenas lectus sapien</h2>
                <p>In posuere eleifend odio. Quisque semper augue mattis wisi. Pellentesque viverra vulputate enim. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```