# Margin is not applied on child div

Tags: css, margin

```css
.search {
  margin: 10px;
}

.search::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: url('magnifying-glass.svg');
}

input[type="search"] {
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  outline: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="search">
    <form>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am fairly new to css. According to my assumptions, my `input[type="search"]` should have 10px margin to the borders of the `div.container` because I have set the `margin` on `div.search`, however, as you can see in code snippet above, my `input` element and `div.container` is sharing borders.

Can you eloborate on what I am missing to make it work? I am especially interested to see the flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: search about collapsing-margin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS margin terror; Margin adds space outside parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685967/is-it-a-bug-margins-of-p-element-go-outside-the-containig-div

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

```
.search {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

### Explanation

The margins between `.container` and `.search` collapse, based on the margin collapsing rules in effect about parent and child elements.

Excerpt from the releveant [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing):

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block; or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Based on that you can prevent collapsing margins by creating a new [block formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) context. This can be done by e.g. setting `display: inline-block` on the the child element.

### In action

```css
.search {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.search::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom:auto;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: url('magnifying-glass.svg');
}

input[type="search"] {
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    outline: none;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test HTML and CSS</title>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="search">
                <form>
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```